# Openlayers: two legend - right e left

Tags: openlayers, legend

I'm using the example https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/legend/map.control.legend.html to create a legend. But I need two: one on the right and one on the left, but I'm not able to set the position so that it is correctly on the map. Any suggestion?
[image: s]

Comment: If you specify className in the control constructors you can use css to position them.

Comment: @Mike Could you give me an example of how to create the subtitles? My code looks like this:  
 var legend_left = new ol.legend.Legend({ 
  margin: 2,
  size: [30, 18],
 });
 
 var legend_right = new ol.legend.Legend({ 
  margin: 2,
  size: [30, 18],
 });
 
        map.addControl(new ol.control.Legend({ 
  collapsible: false,
  legend: legend_left,
 }));
 
 map.addControl(new ol.control.Legend({ 
  collapsible: false,
  legend: legend_right
 }));

Answer (score 0):

Example using two legends (a timeout is used to ensure the icon is loaded before adding it to the legends).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/css/fontmaki.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/css/fontmaki2.css" />
  <!-- FontAwesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Openlayers -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,Object.assign"></script>

  <!-- ol-ext -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>
  <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>

  <!-- ol-ext maki and fontawesome defintions used in fontsymbol -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/extra/FontAwesomeDef.js"></script>

  <style>
    .options canvas {
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 60px;
    }
    button {
      margin: .5em 0;
    }
    input[type="number"] {
      width: 4em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body >

  <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px;"></div>

  <style>
    .ol-legend li:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,60,136,.5);
    }
    .ol-saveas {
      display: none;
    }

.ol-control.ol-legend-left {
  bottom: .5em;
  left: .5em;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.ol-control.ol-legend-right {
  bottom: auto;
  top: .5em;
  left: auto;
  right: .5em;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
  // Layers
  var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.Stamen({ layer: 'watercolor' }) });
    
  // The map
  var map = new ol.Map ({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View ({
      zoom: 6,
      center: [166326, 5992663]
    }),
    layers: [layer]
  });

  // Style function
  function getFeatureStyle (feature) {
    var st= [];
    // Shadow style
    st.push (new ol.style.Style ({
      image: new ol.style.Shadow ({
        radius: 15
      })
    }));
    var st1= [];
    // Font style
    st.push ( new ol.style.Style ({
      image: new ol.style.FontSymbol({
        form: "marker", 
        glyph: 'fa-car', 
        radius: 15, 
        offsetY: -15,
        fontSize: .7,
        color: '#fff',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill ({
          color: 'blue'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
          color: '#fff',
          width: 2
        })
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
        width: 5,
        color: '#f00'
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill ({
        color: [255, 0, 0, 0.6]
      })
    }));
    return st;
  }

  // Vector layer
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    style: getFeatureStyle
  })
  map.addLayer(vector);

  // Add features
  /* */
  var f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon([[[30000, 6300000], [-200000, 6000000], [300000, 6000000], [34000, 6300000]]]));
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f);
  f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.LineString([[400000, 6000000], [680000, 5900000], [690000, 6100000], [420000, 6200000]]));
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f);
  /* */
  var f0 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(    [269914, 6248592]));
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f0);

  /* */
  // Add features with style
  f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point( [500000, 6300000]));
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f);
  f.setStyle (new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      radius: 18,
      radius2: 7,
      points: 5,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({ color: [255,128,0,1], width: 1.5 }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill ({ color: [255,255,0,.3], width: 1 })
    })
  }));
  // Add features with style
  var f1 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(    [500000, 6100000]));
  f1.setStyle (new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({ src:"https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/data/camera.png" })
  }));
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f1);
  // Add features with style
  var f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon([[[30000, 5600000], [-100000, 5900000], [300000, 5800000], [34000, 5600000]]]));
  f.setStyle (new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'cyan'  }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'blue', width: 2, lineDash:[5,8]})
  }));
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f);
  // Add features with style
  var f = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.LineString([[400000, 5900000], [680000, 5800000], [690000, 5700000], [420000, 5600000]]));
  f.setStyle ([ 
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'blue', width: 8})
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#fff', width: 4})
    })
  ]);
  vector.getSource().addFeature(f);

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Define a new legend
    var legendLeft = new ol.legend.Legend({
      title: 'Left Legend',
      style: getFeatureStyle
    });
    var legendCtrlLeft = new ol.control.Legend({ 
      legend: legendLeft,
      className: 'ol-legend ol-legend-left',
      collapsed: false
    });
    map.addControl(legendCtrlLeft);
    legendLeft.addItem({ title: 'Car placemark', feature: f0 });

    // Define a new legend
    var legendRight = new ol.legend.Legend({
      title: 'Right Legend',
      style: getFeatureStyle
    });
    var legendCtrlRight = new ol.control.Legend({ 
      legend: legendRight,
      className: 'ol-legend ol-legend-right',
      collapsed: false
    });
    map.addControl(legendCtrlRight);
    legendRight.addItem({ title: 'Camera placemark', feature: f1 });
  
  }, 1000);

</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's just what I needed. I changed the css to show both subtitles at the top. A question, how do I change the x button color? I didn't find it in the css.

Comment: It is `background` in `.ol-control.ol-legend button.ol-closebox` in the ol-ext css

Comment: Thanks. Also changed `color` in `.ol-control.ol-legend button.ol-closebox:before`. Is it possible to insert a caption, type Caption, to show when hovering over the caption component?